# HTML Grid with circles in intersections

Tags: html, intersection, tic-tac-toe

I'm going to implement the below image in HTML, it is for a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

But I have no idea how to add the circles both for slots and dies.

The board size is dynamic (not always 3x3).

I think it can be done with the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements, but how do I find the intersections?

[image: Tic Tac Toe]

### UPDATE

I made this ([check the code at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0zq7awk/)).
Now I need to draw line between circles both horizontal and vertical.
Any ideas here?

[image: HTML result]

### Update 2

I did it! ([check the code at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfa45mvp/)).

Thanks for your helps. <3

[image: final result]

Comment: Since you know the center and the sides, I presume, you could use a relative positioned container with absolute positioned pieces, with CSS [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()).

Comment: because it is isometric, i thinks you can use (`left + n * interval`) to get the value of `margin-left` in px and use `position: absolute`

Comment: @StackSlave I updated my question and did what you said, now how to add the lines?

Answer (score 2):

```css
#board { 
            display: flex;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: antiquewhite;
            padding: 100px;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        
        #board > div {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        #board > div > div,
        #board > div > div.white,
        #board > div > div.black {
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: black;
        }
        
        #board > div > div.white::after {
            content: "";
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: -50px;
            position: relative;
            left: -50px;
            background: white;

        }
        
        #board > div > div.black::after {
            content: "";
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: -50px;
            position: relative;
            left: -50px;
            background: black;
        }
```

```html
<div id="board">
        <div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <div class="white"></div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <div class="black"></div>       
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="white"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

How about something like this?

Comment: Thank you for the code, it has a problem: the background color must be inside the circles not outside. I updated my question with my solution, but I need help drawing the lines between circles. Thanks again. <3

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

using jquery or javescript build `div` with attributes`border-radius` in css to draw the circle

then, set the `margin-left` to that div by `left + n * interval` and `position: absolute`

Comment: Can you please show me with code? I have updated my question and provided my code. Thanks.